# Can't create stored function - wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I've got the following Problem.

I want to create a stored function which converts an entity_id into the corresponding sku

Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `id2sku`(`entity_id_in` INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnvalue varchar(50);

    SELECT `sku` INTO returnvalue FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id = entity_id_in LIMIT 1;

    return returnvalue;
END
```

Now my problem is if i fire the query i get the following message:
[Window Title]
Error

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT' at line 3
```

The db im using is MySQL 5.0.51a

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL by default uses `;` as a delimiter, so when it encounters the `;` at line 9:

```
 DECLARE returnvalue varchar(50);
```

MySQL thinks the command ends - it is trying to execute:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `id2sku`(`entity_id_in` INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnvalue varchar(50);
```

which isn't valid SQL.

Set a new delimiter:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION `id2sku`(`entity_id_in` INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnvalue varchar(50);

    SELECT `sku` INTO returnvalue FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id = entity_id_in LIMIT 1;

    return returnvalue;
END
$$
```

You can then change the delimiter back with:

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `id2sku`(`entity_id_in` INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE returnvalue VARCHAR(50);

    SELECT `sku` INTO returnvalue FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id = entity_id_in LIMIT 1;

    RETURN returnvalue;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You had not specified the varchar length. :-)

Comment: Nice, i think you are very close. I still get the following error, though. [Window Title]
..."for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9"

Comment: if i could i would accept both answers because both of you were right.

Comment: I have just copied and paste your code but generating the error `Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted`. Please help me what is wrong here ? I am using mysql version `5.5.30-log`.